# Angular input/select box left outline not picking proper radius. when i have tried to custom radius

Tags: css, angular8

I have attach an output image.

> CSS

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

> Output Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.mat-form-field-outline-end` and `.mat-form-field-outline-start` is contained within a flexbox. The issue is that `.mat-form-field-outline-start` has a width smaller than the border-radius.

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-end {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-start {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this is working with border-radius important. Thanks